# Why is the following statement false?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If a sequence $$ \{a_n \} $$  converges, then the sequence  $$ \{a_n/n \} $$ converges to zero. This seems true to me. 
Could an example be provided for why this isn't the case?

Comment: Why would you believe it wouldn't hold?

Comment: It is actually true. Suppose $a_n \to a$ as $n \to \infty$. Then $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n} =\lim_{n \to \infty}\left( a_n \cdot \frac{1}{n} \right)= \left(  \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \right)\cdot \left(  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \right) = a\cdot 0 = 0$$

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification. The solution sheet had marked it as false for some reason, so I was confused.

Comment: No problem!  No thing can be expected to be flawless, especially the answer sheet!  (happens all the time here sadly)

Comment: If  $(a_n)_n$ converges to $A$ then there are only finitely many n for which  $|a_n-A|\geq 1$ . So for all but finitely many $ n$ we have $|a_n/n|\leq (1+|A|)/n$.